# Does it make sense to test time-based fields ? (golang)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, time, go, mocking

I have several structs with fields of type `time.Time`. I'm wondering what's the best practice to test them? Should I simply set the `time.Time` fields to nil and test the rest of the struct (i.e. reflect.DeepEqual)? Otherwise is there a way  make the time deterministic? 
Given the function below how would you test it?

```
type mystruct struct {
    s string
    time time.Time
}

// myfunc receives a string and returns a struct of type mystruct
// with the same string and the current time.
func myfunc(s string) mystruct {
   return mystruct{s: s, time: time.Now()}
}
```

Comment: That's a strange question: Why not just test them? And how can a time.Time be nil? It cann't.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase the question. How can I test a generated timestamp  e.g. on this function `func something()time.Time{ return time.Now()}` how can I test the value returned ?

Comment: What do you mean by test? Test if two times are the same? you can use time.Equal

Comment: @siritinga yeah, test if they are the same. How exactly can you do that? See the function from question and write a test. I know how to compare two time values. The question is totally different.

Comment: Don't try to test `time.Now()`. The time package has its own unit tests.

Comment: @JimB What if the beloved programmer returned ``mystruct{s: s}`` instead of ``return mystruct{s: s, time: time.Now()}``? Shouldn't I test that? The only thing that really bothers me is that I have this struct with a timestamp and I usually do a reflect.DeepEqual but as we have timestamp field returned I was wondering what should I do about it as it breaks the comparison. I'm considering to overwrite it and do the reflect.DeepEqual afterwards. At most I would do a time.After comparison but I thought there may be a better way to make the time deterministic during tests thus the question.

Comment: If you want to check if a user didn't set the time, then just check that field: `mystruct.time.IsZero()`. Sometimes you can't compare structs as a whole. Make an `Equal` method for your struct of you want.

Comment: Have a look how net/http/cookiejar does testing including timestamps: Have the actual functions a `now` parameter which is set to time.Now() in code but allows to pass in synthetic times for testing.

Answer (score 3):

In case you need create a fake for time.Now() you can create TimeProvider and use it for getting real time.Now() or fake it.

This is very simple example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type TimeProvider interface {
    Now() time.Time
}

type MyTimeProvider struct{}

func (m *MyTimeProvider) Now() time.Time {
    return time.Now()
}

type FakeTimeProvider struct {
    internalTime time.Time
}

func (f *FakeTimeProvider) Now() time.Time {
    return f.internalTime
}
func (f *FakeTimeProvider) SetTime(t time.Time) {
    f.internalTime = t
}

func main() {
    var t MyTimeProvider
    f := FakeTimeProvider{t.Now()}
    fmt.Println(t.Now())
    fmt.Println(f.Now())
}
```